# Docker compose of mutiple sub-website

Tags: php, mysql, linux, nginx, docker

I am using Docker compose to run `nginx+php+mysql` environment,OS is centos 7.2, question is about mutiple sub-website  on one host:

For example:
There is one host,two projects will run on this host,
named `project-a` and  `project-b`,
two different `docker-compose.yml` exsist in project-a and project-b.

#### Question:

When executing `docker-compose up` in project-a and project-b,does `nginx+php+mysql` environment run two or one? If two, a lot of space is occupied ,how to solve this problem?

**Add:**  docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:

    nginx:
      container_name: nginx
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443
      links:
        - php
      env_file:
        - ./.env
      working_dir: /usr/share/nginx/html   # should be `/usr/share/nginx/html/project-a` and `/usr/share/nginx/html/project-b` here?
      volumes:
        - ~/docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        - ~/docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        - ~/docker/www:/usr/share/nginx/html

    php:
      container_name: php
      image: fpm
      links:
        - mariadb
        - redis
      env_file:
        - ./.env
      volumes:
        - ~/docker/www:/usr/share/nginx/html

    mariadb:
      container_name: mariadb
      image: mariadb
      env_file:
        - ./.env
      volumes:
        - ~/opt/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql

    redis:
      container_name: redis
      image: redis
```

**.env**:
`project-a` and `project-b`have  different `DB_DATABASE` and `APP_KEY`,other items are the same.

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa   # Here different.

DB_HOST=laravel.dev
DB_DATABASE=project-a   # Here different.
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=laravel.dev
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

**Project files**:
`project-a` and `project-b` have the same catalog.
[image]

**urls**:
`project-a`:aaa.xxxxxx.com
`project-b`:bbb.xxxxxx.com

**Project folders**:
`project-a`:~/docker/www/project-a
`project-b`:~/docker/www/project-b

#### Subsidiary question:

1、Should `working_dir` be `/usr/share/nginx/html/project-name` or `/usr/share/nginx/html` in `docker-compose.yml` file?

2、If `working_dir` is `/usr/share/nginx/html`,I think `docker-compose.yml` files have  the same content in `project-a` and `project-b`,right?Is there any other items to be modified?

3、How to merge the compose file into one?

### Add2:

#### project-common:  `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:

    nginx:
      container_name: nginx
      image: nginx

    php:
      container_name: php
      image: fpm

    mariadb:
      container_name: mariadb
      image: mariadb

    redis:
      container_name: redis
      image: redis
```

#### project-a:  `docker-compose.yml`,and project-b is the same except project name.

```
version: '2'

services:

    nginx:
      external_links:
        - project-common:nginx
      ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443
      links:
        - php
      env_file:
        - ./.env
      working_dir: /usr/share/nginx/html/project-a
      volumes:
        - ~/docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        - ~/docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        - ~/docker/www/project-a:/usr/share/nginx/html/project-a


    php:
      external_links:
        - project-common:php
      links:
        - mariadb
        - redis
      env_file:
        - ./.env
      volumes:
        - ~/docker/www:/usr/share/nginx/html/project-a


    mariadb:
      external_links:
        - project-common:mariadb
      env_file:
        - ./.env
      volumes:
        - ~/opt/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql


    redis:
      external_links:
        - project-common:redis
```

Comment: You can either merge the compose file into one, or use `external_links` (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external-links) to reuse an existing container.

Comment: @warmoverflow  thanks, I added `docker-compose.yml` ,could you please answer the subsidiary question?

Comment: The answer depends on the actual project content you have. `working_dir` only influence the entry script you run in the container. If it is the official nginx image, I would say it does not matter. Does your two projects have different `.env` files? If so you need to merge them into 1. You only posted on yml, so I don't know what the other one looks like. Does your projects have different urls? It seems that all host files are mounted from the home folder so I don't know where you loaded your project specific files.

Comment: @warmoverflow  I added `.env` file ,catalog of project ,urls

Comment: Please remove your app key from your post, and make sure you change it when you deploy.

Comment: @warmoverflow thanks,I removed it.

Comment: It does seem that you can merge the compose files. Need to ensure: 1. your nginx conf is properly configured to serve the files for both urls. 2. your two projects are not use the same database name (both mariadb and redis). 3. you can have separate app_key and db_name for two apps, for example `app_key_a`, `app_key_b`, in the env file, but you'll need to change the corresponding places in your PHP files. Other than these, your compose file seems fine.

Comment: @warmoverflow thanks,I tried it,and I find using `external_links` should be more flexible,right?I want to build a common `php+nginx+mariadb` container group,every project could invoke them,I added 2 yml files,I don't know they are right or not,could you please give some suggestions?

Comment: Your usage of `external_links` is wrong. If you link to an external container, then you don't need to bring up a container of the same type in your compose file. I still think merging is the best solution, but you need some modification. But same for external linking. You'll need to make changes if you want your apps to share a database.

Comment: can anyone create answer with workable example? I also had similar problem to run docker composer

Comment: Guys, running containers are not so expensive in terms of storage as they use the same immutable images which are basically stores environment data. The whole concept of docker was creation lightweight environment snapshots for every single process and tie together different projects into the same containers completely ruins the idea.

Comment: "If two, a lot of space is occupied ,how to solve this problem?" - No. 1. You mound folders, not copying. 2. It is very cheap (about 1,5MB memory per container).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run nginx and php-fpm in different containers. (if your projects share same php version)

You run fpm as a service and in the same container run nginx in daemon-mode-off.

Then you go to nginx config and setup multiple subdomains.

Then setup data-volumes / shared folders according to your subdomain setup.

So you have single nginx/fpm instance which serves multple projects, and some other database/service containers

Answer (score 0):

I agree with strangeqargo, you need only one container on which you can mount 2 volumes..

If the 2 projects use the same PHP and MariaDB version, just configure them correctly to use different databases but on the same container

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I agree with both strangeqargo and intuix.

However, if you should require isolation between the sites, it would be best to setup separate php-fpm pools and separate users for each site, by have separate definitions in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/` with different unix sockets.

Each site definition in nginx should use the corresponding socket of the php-fpm pool.

This gives quite a good explanation on how to do that:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-multiple-websites-securely-with-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-14-04